# hashtag pattern formula in java

Tags: java

I m trying to code up the following figure using hashtag and a bunch of for loops:

[image: the actual hashtag figure]

My code:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
    if( i % 3 == 0 ) 
       System.out.println();
    else 
       System.out.print(" # ");
    for(int j = i + 2 ; j < 10 ; j++){
        if( j % 2 == 0 ) 
           System.out.print(" #");
        else 
           System.out.println();
    }
}
```

But i still can't get it right , please give me some hint!

Comment: I suggest you have a method which prints N * some character.  Then call this with spaces, hashes, spaces (could be zero), hashes and a new line.

Comment: Is this an assignment? Are there any other conditions that need to be met besides printing the above onto the screen?

Comment: I can't make out any connection between your code and your goal. Looks like just some random code involving loops and prints. It doesn't even qualify for an "attempt".

Comment: Oh no, now `#` is known as "hashtag". :'( It's called a "hash" or "number sign", or "pound sign" in the US.

Comment: Additionally, the picture you have pasted uses a variable-width font. You can't get that picture on the console.

Comment: @sftrabbit: Visit us at `#fuddruckers`...

Comment: @sftrabbit How about "octothorpe"? :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Or that!

Comment: @sftrabbit, ok - I obviously can't print the actual figure - so I TYPE IT IN WORD!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here's a Hint.**

Let's put the number of hashes and spaces for each line into a table and look for patterns.

```
ROW  SPACE  HASH   SPACE  HASH
1    0      1      n      1
2    1      2      n-4    2
3    2      3      n-8    3
4    3      n-4
```

*n = number of spaces between the two hashes on the first line*

Now you need to loop through each row and output the proper number of spaces and hashes, and then do the same backwards.  This should be a good hint.  Good luck!

Comment: this is a really good idea - i try it in the future!

Comment: basically find the pattern through looking at num of spaces/row etc